# free complex amplitudes for qubits in Qiskit runtime

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, qiskit-runtime

When I try to run circuits with  `initialize()`,or `StatePreparation()`, I get

```
"Circuits that do not match the target hardware definition are no longer supported after March 4, 2024."
```

Therefore, my question is: is there any other way to freely initialize complex amplitudes for the qubits and run on real quantum device?